# Examples of non-Kähler Calabi-Yau 4-folds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

By a Calabi-Yau manifold, I mean a compact complex manifold whose canonical bundle is trivial and 
$$H^i (X, O_X) = H^0(X, \Omega_X^i) = 0$$ for $0 < i < \dim X$.
Infinitely many topological types of non-Kähler Calabi-Yau 3-folds have been constructed.
Are there any examples of non-Kähler Calabi-Yau 4-folds or higher dimension?

Comment: There are torus $T^2$ fibrations over a Kahler CY base constructed in a paper of Goldstein-Prokushkin. And maybe also compact complex Lie groups (having trivial canonical bundle but I don't think have a Kahler metric).

Comment: @ChrisGerig >>compact complex Lie groups<< 

they are indeed not even symplectic unless abelian, but admit a plenty of holomorphic forms